# Extra mouse button not recognized

Tags: mouse, xev

I have an ASUS mouse (ROG Gladius 2) but the extra mouse buttons are not recognized as mouse buttons in Ubuntu. With the software from ASUS (while working in Windows), I can assign a keyboard or mouse functions to the extra mouse buttons, but I cannot simply say this extra key needs to be an extra mouse button so that I can use it in Ubuntu.

When I assign to the extra mouse buttons a multimedia function like turning up the volume, it also works in Ubuntu. Changing DPI with a mouse button also works.

The keyboard functions are not working. Like emulating pressing <kbd>Control</kbd> or a letter. It works on Windows but not on Ubuntu.

While using `xev`, it noticed that the mouse buttons aren't recognized at all in Ubuntu as mouse buttons. In the past one could download btnx - Button Extension but this software is not available anymore.

So my question is, what is needed to get Ubuntu  torecognize all my extra mouse buttons as extra mouse buttons?

Comment: see [Ubuntu wiki X Config Input](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Input) and [Many Mouse Buttons](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Input)